# ¿Cómo cambiar colores a gráfica con varios geom_bar?

Tags: r

Tengo esta data

```
  x        grupo        y
<int>      <fctr>     <int>
  1         Prod        7       
  2         Prod        5       
  3         Prod        7       
  4         Prod        8       
  5         Prod        7       
  1          Log        6       
  2          Log        5       
  3          Log        8       
  4          Log        6       
  5          Log        9   

ggplot(data = datos) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y)) +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  theme_minimal()
```

produce la siguiente grafica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero se necesita cambiar los colores de las barras o que queden de este estilo de color

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado estos codigos pero aun nada

```
ggplot(data = datos) +      #este codigo solo cambia las linea de afuera de cada barra 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y), colour = "red") +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  theme_minimal()


ggplot(data = datos) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y), position = "dodge2") +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  theme_minimal()


ggplot(data = datos) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y)) +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

Entre otros pero aun nada sigue siendo negro dentro de las barras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te falta es definir una nueva dimensión, en este caso, el color y mapear la misma a la variable de datos que quieres que la gobierne. Viendo tu gráfico entiendo que esa dimensión la maneja el `grupo`:

```
ggplot(data = datos) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y, fill=grupo)) +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Usamos `fill`, que es la estética que gobierna el color de "llenado" de cada barra y la relacionamos con el `grupo`, hay un default de colores y si lo deseas, puedes modificarlos por alguna de las funciones `scale_fill_*` que sean consistentes con una escala de valores discreta (en este caso), por ejemplo tienes `scale_fill_manual()`, para definir exactamente cada color, obviamente la cantidad de colores debe ser consistente con la cantidad de barras.

```
ggplot(data = datos) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = grupo, y = y, fill=grupo)) +
  facet_grid(x ~.) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#132f49","#56b86f")) +
  theme_minimal()
```